# Get version of project from pom.xml

Tags: java, maven

I have this `pom.xml` :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>es.ja.xxx.yyy.aaa</groupId>
        <artifactId>name-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
</project>
```

I need to get the version of my `pom.xml` from the Java code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll explain it backwards:

1. Show value in a facelet (not requested by OP)
2. The managed bean serving the values
3. pom.xml to create manifest.mf

So let's start to show the revision number:

```
<h:outputText value="#{appInfo.revision}" />
```

The result looks like this, where `0.0.40` is the `version` out of the poms project version:

```
0.0.40 / 29.05.2018 12:42
```

As you see the (as shown below) the result shows the revision and the build date. Be tolerant, the following code uses `version` for the build date.

`appInfo` is an ApplicationScoped bean and fetches the version/revision info from manifest. Here are the relevant parts of the bean:

```
@Named
@ApplicationScoped
public class AppInfo {

  private String    revision; // + getter

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {

    InputStream is = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
                     .getResourceAsStream("/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");
    Manifest manifest = new Manifest();
    try {
        manifest.read(is);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // error handling
    } finally {
        try {
          is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          // error handling
        }
    }
    Attributes attr = manifest.getMainAttributes();
    String implRevision = attr.getValue("Implementation-Build");
    String implVersion = attr.getValue("Implementation-Version");

    if (implRevision == null || implVersion == null)
        this.revision = "unknown";
    else
        this.revision = implVersion + " / " + implRevision;
  }
}
```

The buildnumber is fetched from pom.xml by  maven build number plugin (http://www.mojohaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/) and the manifest is generated by maven war plugin.

In the build part of your pom you

1. put the revision info inside a variable (called `${buildNumber}`)
2. use this value to generate manifest

Snippets from pom.xml:

```
 <project>
   <build>
     <plugins>

        <!-- revision number to ${buildNumber} -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>create</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <format>{0,date,dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm}</format>
                <items>
                    <item>timestamp</item>
                </items>
                <doCheck>false</doCheck>
                <doUpdate>false</doUpdate>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- END: revision number to ${buildNumber} -->

        <!-- START: generate MANIFEST.MF -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                    </manifest>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <version>${project.version}</version>
                        <Implementation-Build>${buildNumber}</Implementation-Build>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- END: generate MANIFEST.MF -->

    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Because I have created this a while ago some parts may be (a little bit) outdated, buth they still work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from my live Wicket project build in Eclipse.
Path will be different in Your, analyse Your WAR with any ZIP tool, 7-Zip or similar.

```
try {
            InputStream propIs = getServletContext()
                    .getResourceAsStream("/META-INF/maven/MyProject/MyProject/pom.properties");
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.load(propIs);
            propIs.close();

            mavenVersion = (String) properties.get("version");
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            mavenVersion = "unknown";
        }
```

Update:  such snippet has nothing to web framework used (JSF/Wicket).